# Phonegap/Cordova FileTransfer - Error 3 - Android

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have upgraded to the latest version of Phonegap 3.0.0. This seems to have introduced an intermittent upload error issue.

I have a simple application for uploading a photo.
I select a photo, then push upload.

Randomly it will return "error code 3". This is from what I understand a connection issue.
In the code I am outputting the progress of the upload. The error randomly occurs at different stages of the upload.

The basic stripped down version of the code is

```
function getPhoto(source) {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
        destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: source });
}

function onPhotoDataSuccess(img) {
    imgUrl = img;
    $('#smallImage').attr('src',imgUrl);
}

function doUpload() {

    ft.onprogress = function(progressEvent) {
        if (progressEvent.lengthComputable) {
                var perc = Math.floor(progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total * 100);
                $("#status").text("Uploading: " + perc + "%");
        } else {
                if($("#status").text() == "") {
                    $("#status").text("Uploading");
                } else {
                    $("#status").text( $("#status").text() + ".");
                }
        }
    };

    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey="image";
    options.fileName=imgUrl.substr(imgUrl.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    options.mimeType="image/jpeg";
    options.chunkedMode = false;

    ft.upload(imgUrl, baseURL + "?do_upload", uploadSuccess, uploadFail, options, true);
}
```

I have covered things other people have suggested even though I don't think its related due to the intermittent nature

- Added true to the end of the upload command to enable self signed SSL. I am not using SSL anyway.
- Changed the access origin in the config.xml
- Disabled chunked mode

Does anyone know what else it could be?

**Update:**

I managed to get the error to occur under a VD which gave me logs

```
08-29 15:06:55.172: D/FileTransfer(531): upload content://media/external/images/media/14 to http://exampledomain.com?page=do_upload
08-29 15:06:55.172: D/FileTransfer(531): fileKey: image
08-29 15:06:55.172: D/FileTransfer(531): fileName: 14
08-29 15:06:55.172: D/FileTransfer(531): mimeType: image/jpeg
08-29 15:06:55.172: D/FileTransfer(531): params: {}
08-29 15:06:55.172: D/FileTransfer(531): trustEveryone: true
08-29 15:06:55.172: D/FileTransfer(531): chunkedMode: false
08-29 15:06:55.172: D/FileTransfer(531): headers: null
08-29 15:06:55.172: D/FileTransfer(531): objectId: 1
08-29 15:06:55.172: D/FileTransfer(531): httpMethod: POST
08-29 15:06:55.192: D/FileTransfer(531): Content Length: 15007
08-29 15:06:55.202: D/FileTransfer(531): Sent 15007 of 15007
08-29 15:06:55.202: W/PluginManager(531): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to FileTransfer.upload blocked the main thread for 54ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
08-29 15:06:55.212: W/FileTransfer(531): Error getting HTTP status code from connection.
08-29 15:06:55.212: W/FileTransfer(531): java.io.EOFException
08-29 15:06:55.212: W/FileTransfer(531):    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.Util.readAsciiLine(Util.java:314)
08-29 15:06:55.212: W/FileTransfer(531):    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.RawHeaders.fromBytes(RawHeaders.java:301)
08-29 15:06:55.212: W/FileTransfer(531):    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.readResponseHeaders(HttpTransport.java:130)
08-29 15:06:55.212: W/FileTransfer(531):    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:630)
08-29 15:06:55.212: W/FileTransfer(531):    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:385)
08-29 15:06:55.212: W/FileTransfer(531):    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:334)
08-29 15:06:55.212: W/FileTransfer(531):    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:534)
08-29 15:06:55.212: W/FileTransfer(531):    at org.apache.cordova.filetransfer.FileTransfer$3.run(FileTransfer.java:444)
08-29 15:06:55.212: W/FileTransfer(531):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
08-29 15:06:55.212: W/FileTransfer(531):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
08-29 15:06:55.212: W/FileTransfer(531):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
08-29 15:06:55.223: E/FileTransfer(531): {"target":"http:\/\/exampledomain.com\/?page=do_upload","source":"content:\/\/media\/external\/images\/media\/14","http_status":0,"code":3}
08-29 15:06:55.223: E/FileTransfer(531): java.io.EOFException
08-29 15:06:55.223: E/FileTransfer(531):    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.Util.readAsciiLine(Util.java:314)
08-29 15:06:55.223: E/FileTransfer(531):    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.RawHeaders.fromBytes(RawHeaders.java:301)
08-29 15:06:55.223: E/FileTransfer(531):    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.readResponseHeaders(HttpTransport.java:130)
08-29 15:06:55.223: E/FileTransfer(531):    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:630)
08-29 15:06:55.223: E/FileTransfer(531):    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:385)
08-29 15:06:55.223: E/FileTransfer(531):    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:334)
08-29 15:06:55.223: E/FileTransfer(531):    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:534)
08-29 15:06:55.223: E/FileTransfer(531):    at org.apache.cordova.filetransfer.FileTransfer$3.run(FileTransfer.java:444)
08-29 15:06:55.223: E/FileTransfer(531):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
08-29 15:06:55.223: E/FileTransfer(531):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
08-29 15:06:55.223: E/FileTransfer(531):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
08-29 15:06:55.223: E/FileTransfer(531): Failed after uploading 15007 of 15007 bytes.
```

**Update**
I have found what appears to be the same issue over at the Cordova bug tracker with no solutions.  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-2293#comment-13753360

Comment: We have the same error with version 2.6.0.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and get it done by updated the newtest  OkHttp jar.
according to Andrew Grieve's advice by URL:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-2293#comment-13753360

I download OkHttpd.jar by URL:
https://github.com/square/okhttp

upzip the jar and copy all class files into to android/libs/cordova-3.1.0.jar

It's well, good luck!